# How to get an IDS list of a Json type object with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

If you wish to obtain a list with the IDS of the Acl class, the problem is that these are contained in a list of Companies in the following way...

COMPANY:CS

```
public class Company
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }      

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "acl")]
    public List<Acl> Acl { get; set; }
}
```

ACL.CS:

```
public class Acl
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }      

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "actions")]
    public List<Action> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

These objects are of JSON type and have the following structure

[image: screenshot]

The image shows an example of what you want to get, a list of the IDS of the ACL object that contains COMPANY

but how can I get to this result? I currently have the following query

```
var servicios = mainViewModel.LoginResponse.Companies
                    .Where(c => c.Principal == true)
                    .Select(c => c.Acl)
                    .ToList();
```

How can I isolate my object and only get a list with the IDS required? What LINQ command do I have to use? any help for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var servicios = mainViewModel.LoginResponse.Companies
                .Where(c => c.Principal == true)
                .SelectMany(c => c.Acl.Select(z => z.Id))
                .ToList();
```